# Mudar o valor de um <h1> com jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Estou fazendo uma chamada ajax e preciso alterar o valor da tag `<h1>` com o response:

```
$('#openTickets').ready(function() {
    var open = $.ajax({
        time: 15,
        url: "/opened-tickets",
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false
    }).responseJSON;

    $('#openTickets').val(open);
});

<div class="value">
    <h1 class="count tkts-total" id="openTickets"></h1>
    <p>Aberto e em dia</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Tenta utilizar html() no lugar de val()

Comment: Outra alternativa é usar o text() ao invez do val()

Comment: @FleuquerLima Funcionou, obrigado :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algumas correções que deves ter em conta.

- **`async: false`** está deprecado, não se usa mais, foi uma ideia péssima do antigamente que foi removida, deprecada.
- usa `$(document).ready(` em vêz de `$('#openTickets').ready(`, pois se usares como está o jQuery não vai encontrar esse elemento se o HTML nõ tiver sido lido, enquanto que `document` é global, disponibilizado ao JavaScript desde o inicio do carregamento da página
- o `$.ajax` é assincrono o que quere dizer que tens de usar a callback `success`
- para mudar conteúdo de elementos HTML com jQuery usa-se `.html()`  ou `.text()`, para mudar o valor de elementos que podem receber valor do utilizador usa-se `.val()`. No caso de um *heading* deves usar `.html()` ou `.text()`.

Assim o teu código poderá ser assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        time: 15,
        url: "/opened-tickets",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(res) {
            $('#openTickets').html(res.responseJSON);
        }
    });
});
```

Nota: não vejo onde estejas a passar `data` ao ajax, presumo que não seja preciso.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/et90eyzm/